# Axios "get" still goes to "then" after error occurs

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, error-handling, axios

When I call `getItem` function with a wrong parameter, it still goes through the `then` part. However the response is just  `Error: Request failed with status code 404`.

How can I avoid getting into the `then` part when an error occurs?

```
getItem = async objectId => {
  const client = await this._getAxiosClient();
  const headers = await this._generateHeaders();

  return client
    .get('/some/url', {
      headers,
    })
    .then(response => {
      ...
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log(error)
    });
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the actual status code is also 404?

Comment: Not sure if I understood well, when I put a consolelog inside `then` I get:

Error: Request failed with status code 404
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:59)
    at XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent (event-target.js:172)
    at XMLHttpRequest.setReadyState (XMLHttpRequest.js:572)
    at XMLHttpRequest.__didCompleteResponse (XMLHttpRequest.js:394)
    at XMLHttpRequest.js:507
    at RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit (EventEmitter.js:189)
    at MessageQueue.__callFunction (MessageQueue.js:366)
    at MessageQueue.js:106

Comment: Whats `response.status` ?

Comment: @JonasWilms if I console log in the 'then' it is `undefined` but if I print it in the axios error handler `error.response.status` is 404

Comment: I do get the feeling that the `.then` never runs but you missinterpret your console output ... Or the code is not as shown. Please create a [mre]...

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. In my axios error handler I was directly returning the error instead of rejecting the promise. So I replaced it with this `return Promise.reject(error);` as pointed out here:
https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors